# Ubuntu 20.04 netplan static configuration gets reset after a while

Tags: networking, ubuntu, static-ip, netplan

Expected behavior:

My netplan configuration is always used and the static IP addresses I configured stay like configured.

Actual behavior:

Somehow the machine "forgets" the configuration and acquires different IP addresses via DHCP.

Netplan config:

"/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml"

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.11/24
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.11/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.1.1
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.2.11/24
```

Where does this behavior come from? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possibly related question on askubuntu.com: [Netplan config file not disabling dhcp](https://askubuntu.com/q/1336359)

Comment: Do you have NetworkManager running?

Comment: @cachius thanks for the reference, I tried the solution. Right now it's okay, but I guess I will have to wait a couple of days.

Comment: @user10489 no, this is a cli only machine